# Word-wrap : break-word adds padding on top of text

Tags: css, text

I have a number of divs containing various user generated copy. The css is on this div is as follows:

```
copy {
    width:200px;
    padding:20px 0px 20px 42px;
    line-height:18px;
    color:#555555;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

When the content is a long string with no spaces `word-wrap:break-word` breaks the copy appropriately but adds an "empty line one top" as if there is a return or `</br>` or something.

`white-space: pre;` seems to fix this problem in the above scenario but adds spacing to all of the other text.

I've used this a number of times successfully but have never seen this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: May be your `html` could help us to understand or make a [jsfiddle like this](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/c78pb/).

Comment: Here's the js fiddle. The difference between the commented out version below and the version above.  http://jsfiddle.net/6YrPh/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the padding of `.copy` to

`padding: 20px 0px 20px 45px;`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNZjW/)

**changed from `42px` to `45px`*